# How to Instantiate a Realm Results<T> Array

Tags: swift, realm

The Realm Swift documentation says that querying a `Results<T>` object returns an array, however, when I try to instantiate a Results array like this: `var allObjects : Results<Object> = []`, I get an error saying that I can't use Results with an array literal.

I know the Realm API Reference says that "**Results instances cannot be directly instantiated**;" but I was wondering if there is some kind of workaround to this.

I am wondering because I want to have a global variable that is instantiated with an empty array and is mutated in the `viewWillAppear` method of a UIViewController class. For example:

```
var allItems : Results<Item> = [] 

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let realm = try! Realm()
    self.allItems = realm.objects(Item.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "description")
}
```

Comment: Can you share the use case in which you would want to do this?  The docs are pretty clear.

Comment: @dmorrow I've updated my answer.

Comment: One case is when the predicates cause crashes and madness, then you might want to work with the raw elements, then convert it back to Results type to be observed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Results` is a type provided by Realm. Although on the outside it behaves like an array, it is actually an abstraction that encompasses Realm's lazy loading mechanism, which isn't exposed to end apps. As a result, it's not possible for third party apps to create new instances of `Results`.

If you just want to hold onto an instance of `Results` created by a Realm query, you can make it an optional instead of trying to pre-emptively instantiate it.

```
var allItems: Results<Item>?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let realm = try! Realm()
    self.allItems = realm.objects(Item.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "description")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Results` generic is not an Array. Its enumerable and subscriptable but its not a CollectionType.

Wouldn't you make `allItems` an optional in this case and then unwrap?

Comment: Thank you for your input. Is there any way to instantiate a Results object?